# R:create new column and value using lapply & apply nested on data.frame list, wrong output

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a list of data frames (here 2 as example).

```
df1 <- read.table(text= "var,X2x,X4x,X6x
101337,4.631833,4.4547,11.097333
345754,3.727433,10.8560,10.536600" ,header=TRUE, sep=",")

 df2 <- read.table(text= "var,X2x,X4x,X6x
101337,5.631833,10.4547,11.097333
345754,5.727433,12.8560,10.536600" ,header=TRUE, sep=",")

dflist <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2)
```

I wanted to use lapply to go through each data.frame and the use apply to do a simple comparison (i.e, check if the value from the second column is greater than the third one), given the result, add a new column with a tag (in the example then new column is called "factor".)

I'm almost there but The output of my script is wrong, returning a list of vectors instead of a list of data.frames with the added column.

here is the code:

```
dfL <- lapply(dflist,function(dfx) {
        apply(dfx,1, function(df) { if(df[3] < (df[4] )) {
      dfx$factor<-"nonNA"} else {dfx$factor<-"NA"}
      }
    )

}
)
```

Could you please explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your approach.  First one is that you are modifying `dfx` from your innermost apply, but you are doing it with a simple `<-` operator instead of the `<<-` operator. The former operator will not affect things outside of a function's scope.  I would also not advocate using `<<-` (see solution here for alternate).

The other issue you have is that you are not specifying what row of the `dfx` to update inside `apply`, so even if you had the `<<-` every row would get updated and you would end up with the final value being whatever the last test comparison produced.

Finally, you are returning the result of the `apply` instead of the modified `dfx` in your `lapply`.

Here, we apply the `transform` function to each data frame to add a `factor` column based on the values of the 3rd and 4th columns in the data frames (referenced here by name).  Notice how I was able to use `ifelse` to avoid the inner `apply`:

```
lapply(dflist, transform, factor=ifelse(X4x < X6x, "nonNA", "NA"))

# $df1
# var      X2x     X4x      X6x factor
# 1 101337 4.631833  4.4547 11.09733  nonNA
# 2 345754 3.727433 10.8560 10.53660     NA
# 
# $df2
# var      X2x     X4x      X6x factor
# 1 101337 5.631833 10.4547 11.09733  nonNA
# 2 345754 5.727433 12.8560 10.53660     NA
```

Here is an unnecessary variation that hews closer to what you were trying to do, for compare/contrast and hopefully so you can see more clearly why yours wasn't working:

```
lapply(dflist, 
  function(dfx) {
    dfx$factor <- ""
    lapply(1:nrow(dfx), 
      function(row.id) {
        dfx[row.id, "factor"] <<- 
          if(dfx[row.id, 3] < dfx[row.id, 4]) "nonNA" else "NA"
    } )
    dfx
} )
```

Notice how I `lapply` in the inner loop instead of `apply` so that I can keep track of the row numbers.  Again, I do not recommend this approach, but it is here for explanatory purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this. You don't need `apply` for vectorized operations.

```
lapply(dflist, function(x){
  x$grp <- "not smaller"
  x$grp[x[ , 3] < x[ , 4]] <- "smaller"
  x
})

# $df1
#     var      X2x     X4x      X6x         grp
# 1 101337 4.631833  4.4547 11.09733     smaller
# 2 345754 3.727433 10.8560 10.53660 not smaller
# 
# $df2
#      var      X2x     X4x      X6x         grp
# 1 101337 5.631833 10.4547 11.09733     smaller
# 2 345754 5.727433 12.8560 10.53660 not smaller
```